# Kendo Read Action - getting the control Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a partial view using a Kendo DropDownListFor and within the Datasource Read action I am passing a function name to get additional parameters eg.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AssignedUserId)
    .OptionLabel("Assign to ...")
    .DataTextField("FullName")
    .DataValueField("UserId")
    .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .DataSource(source => {
        source.Read(read => { **read.Action("GetStaffList", "ManageUser").Data("filterAssigned");** })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)

function filterAssigned(e) {
    // Selector needs to be prefixed "Create_" or "Update_" depending on view/HtmlFieldPrefix.
    var ctl = $("#AssignedUserId").data("kendoDropDownList");
    return {
        staffFilter: (ctl.filterInput.val() || 'empty'),
        selectedId: (ctl.value() || 0)
    };
}
```

Within the "FilterAssigned" function I want to get the Id of the control rather than hardcoding `$("#AssignedUserId").data("kendoDropDownList")`. This is because when creating the View, I am setting the `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Create"` so the actual control id is rendered as "Create_AssignedUserId" and I want to use the same function for Create, Update etc.

I have tried the usual options:

```
this.id
this.attr('id')
this.element.attr('id')
e.sender
```

Telerik state that the 'this' attribute is not obtainable during a read but I have seen no other solution other than the selector method. Basically I am trying to do this:

```
function filterAssigned() {
        var ctl = **this.id**;
        return {
            staffFilter: (ctl.filterInput.val() || 'empty'),
            selectedId: (ctl.value() || 0)
        };
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add the prefix to the id inside the function? Also, just put a `console.log(e);` inside your function to see what properties the object has that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to solve this was to use the razor helper `@Html.IdFor`. The control id this returns includes the HtmlFieldPrefix. The function will now look like ...

```
function filterAssigned() {
    var ctl = $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.AssignedUserId)").data("kendoDropDownList");
    return {
        staffFilter: (ctl.filterInput.val() || 'empty'),
        selectedId: (ctl.value() || 0)
    };
}
```